New generated Flutter app with latest framework shows deprecation warnings
If I generate a new Flutter app with Flutter 3.22.2 (latest release at this point in time) and run it via flutter run -d chrome I get deprecation warnings.

Warning: In index.html:37: Local variable for "serviceWorkerVersion"
is deprecated. Use "{{flutter_service_worker_version}}" template token
instead.
Warning: In index.html:46: "FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint" is
deprecated. Use "FlutterLoader.load" instead.

I would expect a new Flutter app generated with the latest framework does not include deprecation warnings. I guess it makes sense to see such warnings after an upgrade like in Deprecation Warnings in Flutter After Upgrading but for new Flutter apps I would expect that that this works without warnings.
